# Animate all text except first line via slide master

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

When creating a slide master, I can apply "appear" animations to each text level, such that the first level appears on a click, and the second level appears on another click:

[image: Animations on slide master]
*(Note that I don't use any list levels deeper than 2)*

But this means that when I first switch onto the slide in question, I have a slide with a title and no content whatsoever, requiring an additional click to show the first line of text.

This is usually not what I want. Normally I want to have a slide with a title and a single line of text (the first top-level bullet), and then a click to reveal every other line, including all 1st and 2nd level bullets.

Is this possible to configure using a slide master? *(I don't like doing any formatting within the slides themselves as this seems to defeat the object of having a master)*

Answer (score 2):

Set the first bullet animation to appear with previous instead of on mouse click.

[image]